# Storing in string

Tags: java, java-io

This method is not returning valid string.what could be the reason??

```
static BufferedWriter writer = null;
static int maxlines = 100;
public static String getTrimmedResponse(BufferedReader b) 
{

    try {

        int count = 0;
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new StringWriter());

        for (String  line; (line = b.readLine()) != null;) {
            if (count++ % maxlines == 0) 


            line = line.replaceAll("\\n", "");

            String trimmedLine = line.trim();
            if (trimmedLine.charAt(trimmedLine.length() - 1) == '>')
                writer.append(trimmedLine);
            else    
            writer.write(line);
            writer.newLine();
        }



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("texception", e+"");
    }
    return writer.toString();
```

}

Comment: It would be difficult to make your indentation and code blocks more obfuscated.

Answer (score 3):

@Payal Problem is in your return statement

```
writer.toString();
```

it is returning the address of writer object. what you should do is:

```
StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
 writer = new BufferedWriter(strWriter);
```

and

```
return strWriter.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use your `StringWriter` to get the response and don't forget to flush.

Here's your method with some proper formatting :

```
static BufferedWriter writer = null;

public static String getTrimmedResponse(BufferedReader b) 
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    writer = new BufferedWriter(sw);
    int count = 0;

    try {

        for (String  line; (line = b.readLine()) != null;) {
            if (count++ % maxlines == 0) {
                line = line.replaceAll("\\n", "");
            }

            String trimmedLine = line.trim();
            if (trimmedLine.charAt(trimmedLine.length() - 1) == '>') {
                writer.append(trimmedLine);
            } else {
                writer.write(line);
                writer.newLine();
            }
        }

        //writer.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("texception", e+"");
    } finally {
        try {
                            // close flushes before closing
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sw.toString();
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning flushing. (Although you don't really need a separate `flush()` and `close()` but it definitely won't hurt.)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you're trying to output the `BufferedWriter` as a string and not the `StringWriter` it wraps. The correct idiom looks like this:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( sw );
... do your writing into writer ...
return sw.toString();
```

P.S.: And in general it's a good idea to `flush()` your `BufferedWriter` before trying to use the result. Or even better, `close()` it. You can even close your `StringWriter` too, even though it makes no difference in this case, closing your streams and writers is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 1):

`writer` is a buffered writer. Calling `toString` on buffered writer will return the string representation of BufferedWriter class instance:

```
java.io.BufferedWriter@1e311410
```

You will get the string data you wrote to the writer if you call `toString` on the underlying `StringWriter` instance.